# Checking for a specific nested type/tag with boost hana

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

Having fun with boost::hana. I wish to check for a specific nested type that acts like a tag in another type, so I borrow from hana::when_valid example and defined a class is_S along with its SFINAE-enabled specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/hana/core/when.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

#define V(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

struct S_tag { };

struct S {
    using tag = S_tag;
};

struct T {
    using tag = int;
};

template< typename T, typename = hana::when< true > >
struct is_S {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template< typename T >
struct is_S< T, hana::when_valid< typename T::tag > > {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<
        typename T::tag, S_tag >::value;
};

int main () {
    std::cout << "is_S (    S { }) = "; V ((is_S< S >::value));
    std::cout << "is_S (    T { }) = "; V ((is_S< T >::value));
    std::cout << "is_S (float { }) = "; V ((is_S< float >::value));

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++1z sfinae.cpp && ./a.out | c++filt
is_S (    S { }) = 1
is_S (    T { }) = 0
is_S (float { }) = 0
```

Is there a simpler/shorter/more succinct way of writing the same check, in keeping with value-type computation of hana philosophy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I might write:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace hana = boost::hana;


struct S_tag { };
struct S { using tag = S_tag; };
struct T { using tag = int; };

auto tag_of = [](auto t) -> hana::type<typename decltype(t)::type::tag> {
    return {};
};

auto is_S = [](auto t) {
    return hana::sfinae(tag_of)(t) == hana::just(hana::type<S_tag>{});
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "is_S (    S { }) = " << is_S(hana::type<S>{})() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_S (    T { }) = " << is_S(hana::type<T>{})() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_S (float { }) = " << is_S(hana::type<float>{})() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I really love the brevity. The docs are well written and immensely helpful but it takes a while to actually get the feeling for the hana idioms.

Answer (score 1):

I woukd be tempted by:

```
template<class...T>
constexpr std::integral_constant<bool,false> is_S(T const&...){ return {}; }
template<class T>
constexpr
std::integral_constant<bool,std::is_same<typename T::tag,S_tag>{}>
is_S(T const&){ return {}; }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile on my end because when appears to be an incomplete class.

Comment: @eng heh, then replace `when<>` with `std::integral_constant<bool,>`

Comment: what compiler did you use to compile your code? Mine complains of the ambiguity in calling `is_S (S {})`. How is the second is_S a better match?

Comment: @eng fixed the problem.  Needed more `...` and less `,` and a `typename`.

Comment: now it makes sense. I will mark it as accepted although I very much wanted to see a solution using hana.